# Starting processes error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Sorry if this question is 'newbie'

So I have a code that opens some programs that were added to a listbox. These programs range from games to other applications I've made using VB.net to webpages.

I have a problem when I try to start some games. Say I have a button and the code is like this:

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    Dim sDirectory1 = "C:\Games\Company of Heroes 2 Master Collection\RelicCoH2.exe"

    Process.Start(sDirectory1)

End Sub
```

The game is Company of Heroes 2, but it gives me the error 'Cannot find items file' outside of VB. And a few other games have similar errors too, but I can run them myself by directly starting the .exe. Do some programs need more permissions? I've tried running as admin to no avail. Over applications will work, such as applications I've made myself and games with launchers. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean "outside of VB"?  The game likely cant find its data files since you are trying to run it from where ever your app is. use StartInfo to specify the working directly

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, I feel kind of dumb now!